# Reducing repetition of retrieving character array from external data file

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, coding-style

I'm making a class for searching through external data files (test emails). The Method "fill_email" of this is extracting characters from a .txt into character arrays of the nodes until a character '|' appears. 
1) My code requires a temporary pointer, which I'm wondering if I can skip and just .get the characters straight into the node?
2) My code also requires a while loop that needs to be repeated 5 times (once for each field), is there some way I can do a while loop that changes out these fields for me?
P.S. My code requires dynamically allocated arrays, and I was sure to put this method in the private section of my code.

Header portion of email struct and it's node:

```
struct email { // struct for storing email data
    char * sent;    // date and time email was sent
    char * from;    // email address of sender
    char * to;      // email address of reciever
    char * subject;  // subject line of email
    char * contents; // contents of email
};

struct email_node { // node for storing email data and next
    email email_data;
    email_node * next;

};
```

Implementation for filling a pointer of a node from an external data file.

```
int Classify::Fill_email(email_node* & node, char filename[]) {
    char* sent_temp = new char[25];  // These are the five temporary arrays for extracting from the 
    char* from_temp = new char[50];  // external data file and then strcpying to the dynamic character
    char* to_temp = new char[50];    // arrays in the node.
    char* subject_temp = new char[100]; 
    char* contents_temp = new char[500]; 
    int size = 0;

    ifstream source_file(filename);
    //I hate copy/pasting, but I really wasn't sure how to do this for each field otherwise.
    while(source_file.good()) {   // Reads until source_file is empty
        sent_temp[size] = source_file.get();             // It should extract the text from my external file "Sample_Emails.txt" 
        if (sent_temp[size] == '|')
            break;
        size++;                                       // and put them into a temporary array for the field
    }
    sent_temp[size] = '\0'; // So that the character array ends properly.
    size = 0; // Just for the next while loop
    //
    while(source_file.good())  // Goes on for 4 more variables copy pasted....

    email_head->email_data.sent = new char[strlen(sent_temp)]; // For initialziing the field

    strcpy(node->email_data.sent, sent_temp); // Copying the data from the temporary arrays to the fields in the node
    //
    delete sent_temp;
    //
    if(!(source_file.good()))  // If the external data file is empty, return 1
        return 1;
    return 0;
    //
};
```

Comment: Don't use dynamically allocated `char` pointers for strings. Use `std::string`.

Comment: Also, never loop `while (file.good())` or `while (!file.eof())`. The error or EOF flagg will not be set until an attempt to read actually fails which means you might loop one to many and then have the reading fail causing you to add wrong data.

Comment: Oh, and instead of making your own list, why not simple use e.g. `std::vector<email>`?

Comment: Oh an you have an off-by-one error in your code, when you allocate `strlen(sent_temp)` bytes for the string, where you forget to allocate space for the string terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my own advice, I would first change the structure to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of pointer:

```
struct email { // struct for storing email data
    std::string sent;    // date and time email was sent
    std::string from;    // email address of sender
    std::string to;      // email address of reciever
    std::string subject;  // subject line of email
    std::string contents; // contents of email
};
```

Then I would store the structures (nor pointers) in a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<email> emails;
```

Then to read, I would make use of [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (both to read lines from the file, and for tokenization), [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), something like this:

```
int Classify::Fill_email(std::vector<email>& emails, const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream email_file(filename);

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(email_file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream email_line(line);

        email mail;

        std::getline(email_line, mail.sent, '|');
        std::getline(email_line, mail.from, '|');
        std::getline(email_line, mail.to, '|');
        std::getline(email_line, mail.subject, '|');
        std::getline(email_line, mail.contents);

        emails.push_back(mail);
    }
}
```